# Is there a bug reporting library similar to the bug report system on Android Market?

Tags: java, c++, android, debugging

I'm currently using Trac for bug tracking, but I'm looking for a solution to automatically catch/detect/notify remote bugs.

Is there a library/solution for a bug reporting system similar to the one available for Android developers at the Market Developer Console? Briefly, a solution that catches (Or can be programatically controlled) errors on a remotelly running application and sends error info (call stack, etc) to a server. Developers could, then, check the server for the reports.

I'm thinkg in something in Java or C++.

Comment: This is not a duplicated question. I checked the referred questions, and all were asking about the Android system. This question looks for a Java/C++ solution similar to the one provided on Android environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug4j does that.
See http://code.google.com/p/bug4j/

Answer (score 1):

[Instabug](https://instabug.com/) is a bug & crash reporting service that allows for two things:

- Automatically receive crash reports in the event of a crash.
- Allow users to report bugs through a shake gesture in-app.

All reports arrive to your Instabug dashboard containing various details such as

- Network and console logs
- Complete Device details
- Visual reproduction steps
- 3D inspection of the current view hierarchy
- Crash stack trace (In case of a crash report)

You could also send reports based on specific exceptions or triggers that fire within your app.
It only takes a line of code to integrate.

---

For full disclosure, I work at [Instabug](https://instabug.com/). Let me know if I can help.